# Hi I need help in making a global product attribute selector having pop up feature in wordpress, would be glad if anyone can suggest anything

Tags: global-filter

I am trying to get a global product attribute selector as a pop on my website on wordpress as we are a multi city business and we want client to choose the city name using attribute selector assigned individually to all the products, thus after the selection client will see the results as per the city chosen on the website on every page.

I have tried using plugins but not getting the desired result.